# How do I get JButton to send an email? (Java Swing)

Tags: java, email, swing, jbutton

**Here's the code I have installed at the top of my document:**

copied from: http://coders-and-programmers-struts.blogspot.com/2009/05/sending-email-using-javamail-e-mailing.html

```
    package my.planterstatus;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.activation.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Kris
 */


public class PlanterStatusUI extends javax.swing.JFrame
   {

    /** Creates new form PlanterStatusUI */
    public PlanterStatusUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

        public String status = new String(); {
        }

public class TestEmail {
// Send a simple, single part, text/plain e-mail
    public void main(String[] args, String status) {
    // SUBSTITUTE YOUR EMAIL ADDRESSES HERE!!!
    String to = "blah@blahblahblah.com";
    String from = "Planter Status";
    // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP'S MAIL SERVER HERE!!!
    String host = "smtp.blahblah.com";
    // Create properties, get Session
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // If using static Transport.send(),
    // need to specify which host to send it to
    props.put("pop.blahblah.net", host);
    // To see what is going on behind the scene
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
try {
   // Instantiatee a message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    //Set message attributes
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject("PS# " + display.getText()+ " is currently " + status);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    // Set message content
    msg.setText("PS# " + display.getText()+ " is currently " + status);
    //Send the message
    Transport.send(msg);
    }
catch (MessagingException mex) {
    // Prints all nested (chained) exceptions as well
    mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}//End of class
```

**and here's the code I have installed in my button's event handler:**

```
   private void confirmationYesButtonHandler(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
```

The error message I get from netbeans is:

"cannot find variable msg"

The 2 options NetBeans gives me to "solve" the issue are:

1. "Create Field msg in my.planterstatus.PlanterStatusUI"
2. "Create Local Variable msg"

I don't know how to fix this.  From my extremely limited understanding of Java, it looks like the "msg" variable has been fleshed out at the top of the document, but apparently not.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with swing, JButton or sending emails.

Comment: You're right, it's mainly about Animal Husbandry, Spontaneous Fission, and the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `msg` variable you've shown is limited to the `try` block it is within.

Here's a page from the ["Java Made Easy" tutorial on `scope`](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) that appears fairly easy to understand.

Comment: I read the "Scope" article a couple times, but have not gained enough insight to apply it to my issue.  --do I change my button event code to "try.Transport.send(msg);" or how should I proceed?

Comment: Chose option 1. "Create Field msg in my.planterstatus.PlanterStatusUI"

Answer (score 0):

msg is declared in the try block and thus is only visible in the try block.

Comment: edit: nevermind -- Stephen Denne got there first! reps to him. :)